# XML Parser not readable in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am parsing my XML file in HTML and it parses well when I run it in Chrome/Edge browsers, but when I run it in Firefox, it throws this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://127.0.0.1:5500/List.xml
Line Number 21, Column 2:
```

This is my HTML where I parse it:

```
<script>
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xml.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                var xmlData = xml.responseXML;
                if (!xmlData) {
                    xmlData = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml.responseText, 'text/xml');
                    var PDF = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("PDF");
                    var web = PDF[0].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].firstChild.data;
                }
            }
        }

        xml.open('GET', 'List.xml', true);
        xml.send(null);
</script>
```

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>

<List>
    <PDF>
        <id>1</id>
        <link>https://www.mywebpage.com/AA.pdf</link>
    </PDF>
</List>

</xml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is not [*well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134494/290085).  Remove the last `</xml>` tag.

The `<?xml version = "1.0" ?>` construct is not a opening element tag that has to be closed.  It is an *XML declaration*.

Comment: Thanks! I added ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>``` and it worked.